# How to check if CAB file is downloaded by a user in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, cab

I have a page that hosts CAB file like the one below

```
<object id="SOmeID" class="Class1" codebase="..\CAB\Client.cab#version=2,0,0,2" classid="clsid:SomeIDComeshere" VIEWASTEXT >
```

When this page is browsed the first time, there is a message to download the CAB file and is upto the user's choice to download or not
Some users prefer not to download.

Due to this certain pages are not rendered correctly or do not function as they are expected to.

My question:
When client call up to report an issue, how do I check if they have downloaded the cab file or not?
Is there any windows folders i need to check for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ActiveXObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8%28VS.85%29.aspx) object:

```
try { 
   var control = new ActiveXObject(ProgId);
   // installed
}
catch(e) {
   // not installed
}
```